# WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize property not taking

Tags: wcf, exception, maxreceivedmessagesize

Searched with no luck...

I keep getting

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

It makes sense, so I go into both Server and client config and make the change:

Client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUpload"
           closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/services/FileUpload.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUpload"
          contract="CFTW.FileUpload.IFileUpload" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUpload" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Server

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUpload"

                 transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">

        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUpload">
        <endpoint address="~/services/FileUpload.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUpload"
            contract="CFTW.FileUpload.IFileUpload"></endpoint>
      </service>

    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working (otherwise I'd fix it:)).  It's running on .NET 4.0 RC.

Comment: if you're trying to do file upload (as your behavior name seems to indicate), I'd check out WCF streaming instead of just upping the maxreceivedmessagesize parameter....

Comment: Huh...I thought I was doing WCF streaming.  I thought thats what trasferMode="Streamed" was for?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue. I found that my custom binding did not get applied at all. Then I used `name = ""` in binding tag. Then everything started working with the new settings. This is due to .NET 4.0 comes with default binding/endpoint/behavior configurations. These default settings have `name = ""`. I just modified the default binding itself. The reason for my custom binding(named) did not get applied is due to the value for the name in `<service>` tag. It should follow `<Namespace.ServiceClassName>`.

Comment: which binding name did you set to ""? in the client config?

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the attribute `maxReceivedMessageSize` in the client config for the binding. Also, be sure to set the same value for the `maxBufferSize`. For buffered connection these two values need to be same.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, luckily in a second project and could compare with the working project. The difference was that the working project had additional attributes set in the web.config for the service bindings...

Working sample:
httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"

The second project only had:
httpsTransport

Also do a search in your project for 65536 as it is also defined in configuration.svcinfo and configuration91.svcinfo of the service reference.