# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: c#, wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

My WCF Service has an OperationContract that accepts, as a parameter, an array of objects.  This can potentially be quite large.  After looking for fixes for Bad Request: 400, I found the real reason: the maximum message size.

I know this question has been asked before in MANY places.  I've tried what everyone says: "Increase the sizes in the client and server config files."  I have.  It still doesn't work.

My Service's web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="myService">
        <endpoint name="myEndpoint" address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
                  contract="Meisel.WCF.PDFDocs.IPDFDocsService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding"
                 closeTimeout="00:11:00"
                 openTimeout="00:11:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:15:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:15:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My Client's app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPDFDocsService"
                 closeTimeout="00:11:00"
                 openTimeout="00:11:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:11:00"
                 allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                     algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8451/PDFDocsService.svc"
                behaviorConfiguration="MoreItemsInObjectGraph"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPDFDocsService"
                contract="PDFDocsService.IPDFDocsService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IPDFDocsService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MoreItemsInObjectGraph">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What can I possibly be missing or doing wrong?  It's as though the service is ignoring what I typed in the maxReceivedBufferSize.

Thanks in advance,
Kyle

**UPDATE**

Here are two other StackOverflow questions where they never received an answer, either:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880623/maxreceivedmessagesize-adjusted-but-still-getting-the-quotaexceedexception-with

[WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize property not taking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569715/wcf-maxreceivedmessagesize-property-not-taking)

Comment: It looks correct at a glance. Are you configuring the end point in the code anywhere?  If so, that might be overriding the config settings.

Comment: How are you hosting the service? IIS?

Comment: @Jeff: I'm just creating a new instance of my Service Client, then calling the OperationContract, passing in my custom class as a parameter.  Nothing fancy.

@Simon: I'm using the ASP .NET Development Server.  Currently, it's all local.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the service config file, the "name" attribute is missing from the  element

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="StackOverflow">
```

and there should be a reference to this name in the service element:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="StackOverflow" name="myService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
```

**In general, it's a good idea to validate, if not always edit, your WCF config files using the "WCF Service Configuration Editor", which is invoked from the Visual Studio "Tools" menu item.**

Also there is no endpoint behavior defined for the service. I don't know if this matters.

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you that when I add a name to my behavior, the WCFTestClient gives me the error: "Error: Cannot obtain Metadata. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved. Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service. The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.HTTP GET. The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information."  This is why I didn't include a name for my behavior.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the true solution was to this issue, but I was able to get my ORIGINAL problem resolved, making this issue moot.  FWIW, it seems as though I was able to get rid of the above error by making SURE my service used behaviorConfiguration.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with WCF Test and I had set corectly the config file. If isn't any problems from your config file, I suggest try to test the service with another program eg: SOAP UI, I think this error it's not from the service, it's from the WCF Test.