# WCF with netTcpBinding binding and maxReceivedMessageSize error message

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to get my App.Config setup correctly to allow my NetTcp Service to return strings larger than 65536, because Im getting this error below

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

So far this is what I've tried but it doesn't work, I was hoping someone could point out my mistake

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="NetTcpSHWS.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="NetTcpSHWS.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NetTcpSHWS/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="NetRcpEndPoint" address ="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netMyConfig" contract="NetTcpSHWS.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="NetTcpMetadataPoint" address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NetTcpSHWS.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netMyConfig"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Buffered">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is just a test app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265725/wcf-error-the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-bee

Comment: I updated the config settings of my original post with the recommended changes but I'm still getting the error

Comment: How do you start your service?

Comment: No I just localhosted it via vs tools, but I realised I never configured my client side and thats why I was still getting the issue, facepalm

Comment: possible duplicate of [The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908857/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `bindingConfiguration`:

```
<endpoint name="NetRcpEndPoint" bindingConfiguration="myConfiguration" ... >

<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="myConfiguration" ...
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

If you don't, your binding configuration won't be used (the default configuration will be used instead).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I made the changes but Im still getting the error, I updated the config settings in my original post